# View logcat in Android Studio without creating a new project

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I am trying to use Android Studio as my main Android IDE.

One thing i'm used to having from Eclipse is the option to use DDMS to view logcat logs from the attached device.

I cannot seem to be able to achieve the same with Android Studio - it required me to create a new project before i can access logcat.

Is there any way to show logcat output or do i have to create a new project for that ?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is `View/Tool Windows/Android` (Alt+6 shortcut) that gives you access to the logcat

Comment: I'm on a Mac and I don't see a View menu or a Tools menu when I open Android Studio – only when I have a project up... Is it not possible to use logcat without having an open project on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADB, in cli.

```
adb logcat TAG:{V/D/I/W/E/F/S}
```

Check for
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html